# Database checked value exist or not

Tags: magento-1.9

I checked value available in db or not but it's not working

```
    <?php $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'); ?>
    <?php $mpAssignProductModel=Mage::getModel("mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct")->load($id); ?>
    <?php $_product=Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($mpAssignProductModel->getProductId()); ?>

    <?php $sku = $mpAssignProductModel->getsku();?>

<li class="fields">
<div class="customer-name">
<div class="field">
<label class="required" for="sku"><em>*</em><?php echo $helper->__('Sku')?></label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" name="sku" id="sku" class="required-entry input-text" value="
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM marketplace_assignproduct WHERE sku ='$sku'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
{
echo "User exist";
}

else{
echo $mpAssignProductModel->getsku();
} 
?>"/>
</div>
    </div>
        </div>
</li>
```

What is the problem on this

Comment: did you got any output?

Comment: it's not validate if same sku also stored

Comment: if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0)
{
echo "User exist";
}

else{
echo $mpAssignProductModel->getsku();
}   use this condition in your case

Comment: No it's not validate it stored

Comment: if the number of record greater then zero then it will show user exist.. or you can set limit
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM marketplace_assignproduct WHERE sku ='$sku' limit 1"); in that your condition work

Comment: No actually i checked if sku availble or not if available it show's available

Comment: if you passing in query and get the result then off-course it available..

Answer (score 2):

I ***assumed*** that **`marketplace_assignproduct`** is the  *table of model*  ***Mage::getModel("mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct")***.

Now **using** it this **`model resource collection`** (***Mage::getResouceModel("mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct_collection")***)

we can check *`records existence  of that particular sku`*

**just like:**

> ```
> $collection=Mage::getResouceModel("mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct_collection")
>                        ->addFieldToFilter($fieldname, $value)
>             ->setPage(1,1);
>
> if($collection->getSize() >=1):
> // Exiting
> endif;
> ```

---

**For you case it may like this:**

> ```
> <?php
>
> $collection=Mage::getResouceModel("mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct_collection")
>                        ->addFieldToFilter('sku', $sku)
>             ->setPage(1,1);
>
> if($collection->getSize() >=1)
> {
> echo "User exist";
> }
>
> else{
> echo $mpAssignProductModel->getsku();
> } 
> ?>"/>
> ```

### updated

As per as your request,if `you want to use in that text box if user enter same sku it shows error`

---

**Then try this code**:

```
<?php
$collection=Mage::getResouceModel("mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct_collection")
                       ->addFieldToFilter('sku', $sku)
            ->setPage(1,1);

// the condition
if($collection->getSize()<1 || !$collection->getSize()):
?>

// add here your input text
<?php
endif;
?>
```

Comment: how to use that text box for this condition

Comment: did not get ur point..

Comment: check my question i want  to use in that text box if user enter same sku it shows error. so how to use that

Answer (score 0):

To execute the mysql query in magento, you have to follow the below code

```
<?php

    /**
     * Get the resource model
     */
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

    /**
     * Retrieve the read connection
     */
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

    /**
     * Retrieve our table name
     */
    $table = $resource->getTableName('catalog/product');

    /**
     * Set the product ID
     */
    $productId = 44;

    $query = 'SELECT sku FROM ' . $table . ' WHERE sku = '
             . $sku . ' LIMIT 1';

    /**
     * Execute the query and store the result in $sku
     */
    $sku = $readConnection->fetchOne($query);
    /**
    * Print the SKU to the screen
    */
    //echo 'SKU: ' . $sku . '<br/>';
    Now you can check value exist or not using php empty method,


     if(!empty($sku) && $sku != ''){
          //write code for sku available
     } else {
        //write code for sku not available..
     }

?>
```

refer this [link](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/direct-sql-queries/)

### Edit :

Replace your query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM marketplace_assignproduct WHERE sku ='$sku'");
```

with this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM marketplace_assignproduct WHERE sku ='{$sku}'");
```

Comment: can you please give that exact code

Comment: what is $productId and how to use in that textbox

Comment: change that filed name to sku

Comment: No actually i checked if sku availble or not if available it show's available

Comment: @Kothari check my update

Comment: No it's not working simply it's saving